# Comparing two columns in a Grails criteria builder?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

How would I go about converting Grails where syntax comparing two properties, for example,

```
where { prize > entryFee }
```

Into Grails CriteriaBuilder syntax comparing the values of two columns?

Something like,

```
def c = Tournament.createCriteria()
def results = c {
   gt 'prize', tournament.entryFee
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are `*Property` nodes you can use in the criteria for comparing two properties.

In your case, you'd want something like:

```
def c = Tournament.createCriteria()
def results = c {
    gtProperty 'prize', 'entryFee'
}
```

There are also `geProperty`, `eqProperty`, `neProperty`, `ltProperty` and `leProperty` for greater than equal, equal, not equal, less than, and less than equal, respectively.

Comment: Thanks! I feel dumb for missing this, I was just looking at the source at `HibernateCriteriaBuilder.java` and it was right there!

Comment: It's also hidden [in the docs](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html) under createCriteria